# Bash script - search for files whose name matches a pattern

Tags: bash

I am trying to compile a simple bash script. It should search for files whose name matches a supplied pattern (pattern is supplied as an argument) and list a few first lines of the file. All the files will be in one directory.

I know I should use `head -n 3` for listing the first few lines of the file, but I have no idea how to search for that supplied pattern and how to put it together.

Thank you very much for all the answers.

Answer (score 2):

No need really, the shell will do patterns for you:

```
head -3 *.c
==> it.c <==
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

==> sem.c <==
#include <stdio.h>          /* printf()                 */
#include <stdlib.h>         /* exit(), malloc(), free() */
#include <sys/types.h>      /* key_t, sem_t, pid_t      */

==> usbtest.c <==
```

Another example:

```
head -3 file[0-9]
==> file1 <==
file1 line 1
file1 line 2
file1 line 3

==> file2 <==
file2 line 1
file2 line 2
file2 line 3

==> file9 <==
file9 line 1
file9 line 2
file9 line 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Bash has a `globstar` option that when set will enable you to use `**` to search subdirectories:

```
head -3 **/mypattern*.txt
```

To set globstar you can add the following to your .bashrc:

```
shopt -s globstar
```

Comment: That `**` is resulting in exactly the same as `*` in most shells.  Which shell are you working on?

Comment: I am using bash.  From the bash man page: * Matches any string, including the null string.  When the globstar shell option is  enabled, and * is used in a pathname expansion context, two adjacent *s used as a single pattern will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.   If followed by a /, two adjacent *s will match only directories and subdirectories.

Comment: Ah, ok.  That shell option is off by default; maybe you should add that aspect to your answer (how to switch that on etc.), than it becomes a worthy one :)

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -name 'mypattern*.txt' -exec head -n 3 {} \;
```

Add a `-maxdepth 0` before the `-exec` if you do *not* want to descend into subdirectories.

Comment: You can use `\+` instead of `\;` as terminator. This will supply multiple files to the `exec` command.